# How to change the screen resolution of a tablet?

Tags: android, resolution

Is it possible to change the screen resoultion of a tablet device? I'm using a [Lenovo IdeaPad A1 (A107)](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tablet/ideapad/a1/)

By default it's 1024x600 px. I would like to simulate 800x600 and 480x360 for example.

Thanks. Sam

Comment: By changing properties you can often break a machine - I've done similar on a netbook and it never recovered; hacking (which *may* be an option) may not be a safe option! Also, can you explain why you want this as there may be software which can emulate this instead?

Comment: These might be helpful [How to change screen resolution on android rooted device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/how-to-change-screen-resolution-on-android-rooted-device) and [Change android device physical resolution](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22368/change-android-device-physical-resolution)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The resolution is fixed to match the actual device.